# PowerShell Script to get login details

Tags: powershell

Hi I have written the following code to get the login user details, but I'm getting only the system name. I also need the username along with it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
function GetList 
{ param ([string]$base)
$blah = [ADSI]"$base"
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.Filter = "(objectClass=Computer)"
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $blah
$PropList = "cn","operatingsystem"
foreach ($i in $PropList){$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)}
$Results = $objSearcher.FindAll()
foreach ($objResult in $Results)
{
    $OS = $objResult.Properties.operatingsystem
    If ($OS -match "Windows")
    {
        Echo $objResult.Properties.cn 
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code whatsoever getting user details. That code appears to be listing computer operating systems.

Comment: Ya its is listing operating system but i need the system user name instead, how can it be done..

Comment: What do you mean "the system user name"? Is this something specific to the computer? I guess you will have to change your AD search string to something that gives you this user.

Comment: I wonder what `(objectClass=User)` might show...

Comment: What does "system user name" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `$env:USERNAME` is thing you are searching for. There is also `$env:UserDomain` and `$env:ComputerName`.